# Dynamic conversion of Text size in custom view getting wrong in android

Tags: android-layout, uiview, android-custom-view, text-size

I am trying to calculate text size of the EditText dynamically in my custom View.

Following is my code snapshot.

in my values/dimens.xml file, I have defined a size

```
<dimen name="default_view_height">180dp</dimen>
```

I am using this dimension through custom attributes, so I retrieve this, in my CustomView, I have retrieved this value using the following

```
default_view_height = attrsArrays.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CustomView_defaultViewSize,DEFAULT_VIEW_SIZE);
```

and in my customView I am using this value to calculte the size of my EditText View in following way

```
 mInputText.setTextSize(default_view_height / 6);
```

Basically I am trying to dynamically handle the size of the EditTextView's text size in proportion to the size of the CustomView.

I am getting the right proportion on all devices including N5,N4, except Samsung high end devices like Samsung S4.

Whats wrong in the code.